# python code to download outlook attachments

Tags: python, excel, outlook

Script used and error found

```
import win32com.client as win32

import re

import os

​

​

# Get the Outlook application

outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

​

# Get the Inbox folder

inbox = outlook.ActiveSession.GetDefaultFolder(6), Airtel_Remedy_report

​

# Get all messages in the Inbox

messages = inbox.Items()

​

# Download attachments for each message

for message in messages:

    for attachment in message.Attachments:

        attachment.SaveAs(os.path.join('attachments', D:\Remedy_integration_E\Jatin_Python\Air_rem_rep))

        

          target_folder = inbox.Folders['Airtel_Remedy_report'].Folders['D:\Remedy_integration_E\Jatin_Python\Air_rem_rep']

target_folder.Name      

​

  Cell In[3], line 18
    attachment.SaveAs(os.path.join('attachments', D:\Remedy_integration_E\Jatin_Python\Air_rem_rep))
```

I am trying to download outlook attachment to my local computer

Comment: There are several problems here.  File names are strings, and have to contained in quotes, just like to have in the next line.  However, strings with backslashes are problematic.  You either need to make it a raw string (`r"D:\Remedy_integration..."`) or double all the backslahes.

Comment: Also, your line that starts `inbox = outlook.ActiveSession` is wrong.  What is that second parameter supposed to be?